# Powershell Datetime Filter Is Not Using Correct ShortDate Pattern

Tags: powershell

I am trying to filter LastWriteTime on the Get-ChildItem function, however when I try to filter using a british date, it fails because it's not in the American format.

When I run `(Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` I receive `dd/MM/yyy` which is the correct format.

However when I execute the powershell filter statement :-

`GCI 'C:\ | ?{$_.LastWriteTime -ge '21/01/2018'}`

I receive the following :-

`Cannot convert value "21/01/2018" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`

However if I alter the date to `01/21/2018` I receive the correct results.

I have attempted to use `$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('dd-MM-yyyy') -ge '01[![enter image description here][1]][1]/01/2018'` which doen't work correctly as it returns dates from 2017.

[image: PS1]
[image: PS2]

Comment: If you use ISO date formats for all-the-things you should be fine. Alternatively you need to create a `[date]` object that you can use in your comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your date string to a date object first:

```
$date = get-date '21/01/2018'
gci C:\ | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -ge $date }
```